# Heap size issue in JSF web App

Tags: java, jsf, memory, itext, heap-memory

I am building a web application using JSF.I am using glassfish ssrver.I am trying to apply watermark on PDF using iText.It is working good but when I try to apply watermark on a pdf document more than 30MB (conatains more than 5500 pages) , it thorw this exception.

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

root cause

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

root cause
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

    note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 logs.
```

While searching the solution , I found that by setting program size, we can fix this.
So I put these VMargs -`Xms6000m
-Xmx6000m` 
 in that class's run configuration but no effect.
 Now I am unable to understand that what can be the solution?thanks

Comment: "in that class's run configuration but no effect". What do you mean by this ? You should increase heap size for your server Glassfish

Comment: By specifying arguments you only postpone the problem. You need to defeat the cause. Provide us with more context so that we could elaborate more.

Comment: I think it has something to do with iText. I have come across a lot of people facing memory leak issues with iText. It may be due to improper usage(lack of proper documentation) or problem with iText itself, especially if you are using the free version.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi Right, improper use of iText can easily eat up all your memory, especially in web services with concurrent PDF manipulations. viki, check your sources for `PdfReaders` and PDF creation classes which are not closed after use, and avoid the use of in-memory documents (if you handle large PDFs). If you have a 500 MB PDF parsed into memory, it'll eat up more than a GB. If you instead only load it partially, some 100KB will suffice. You might want to make a memory dump in OutOfMemory situations and analyze it.